# Como hacer que un combo box dependa de otro, segun la opcion que escojas en el primero

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox

supongamos que tenemos en sgt codigo que no es mas que 2 combo box con diferente valore

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
raiz =Tk()
raiz.title("hola")
raiz.geometry("1000x850")
raiz.config(bg ="gray")
raiz.config(bd="30")
raiz.config(relief="groove")
miframe = Frame(raiz,bg="white",width="1000", height="650")
miframe.pack(fill ="both",expand = "True")



combobox = ttk.Combobox(miframe,width="30",state="readonly")
combobox["values"]=("Color","Tamaño")
tcombobox.grid(row="5",column="1")

combobox1 = ttk.Combobox(miframe,width="30",state="readonly")
combobox1["values"]=("azul","amarillo","rojo","grande","mediano","chikito")
combobox1.grid(row="6",column="1")


raiz.mainloop()
```

lo que deseo que segun la opcion que se escoja en el primer combo box cargue determinadas opciones en el segungo,,por ejemplo si escojo en el primer combobox la opcion de color en el segundo solo me cargue los valores de azul,,rojo,,amarillo y no salga nada relacionado con el tamaño,,,o si escojo tamaño en el primero que salga en el segundo grande,mediano,chiquito y no salga nada relacionado con el color,otra cosa por supuesto que no se habilte el segundo combobox sin haber escojido algo en el primero,saludos

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

- Usa un diccionario para mapear cada opción del primer combobox con las del segundo.
- Enlaza el evento `ComboboxSelected` del primer combobox a una callback y en ella obtén las opciones del diccionario y actualiza el segundo combobox.

---

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


raiz = tk.Tk()
raiz.title("hola")
raiz.geometry("1000x850")
raiz.config(bg ="gray")
raiz.config(bd="30")
raiz.config(relief="groove")

miframe = tk.Frame(raiz, bg="white", width="1000", height="650")
miframe.pack(fill="both", expand="True")

opciones = {
    "Color": ("azul", "amarillo", "rojo"), 
    "Tamaño": ("grande", "mediano", "chikito")
    }

def on_combobox_select(event):
    combobox1.set("")
    combobox1.config(values=opciones[combobox.get()])

combobox = ttk.Combobox(
    miframe, width="30", state="readonly", values=tuple(opciones.keys())
    )
combobox.grid(row="5", column="1")
combobox.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", on_combobox_select)

combobox1 = ttk.Combobox(
    miframe, width="30", state="readonly"
    )
combobox1.grid(row="6", column="1")


raiz.mainloop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]